# How to get textnode by attribute. ActionScript 3.0

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, textnode

I have this XML

```
<language lang = "ru">
    <ru>language/ru.xml</ru>
    <ua>language/uk.xml</ua>
    <en>language/en.xml</en>    
</language>
```

How I can get a text node that corresponds to an attribute? That is, if the attribute 
**lang = "ru"**, then I get a text node **language/ru.xml**, if **lang = "en"** - **language / en.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have that XML string in a variable called xml, you would get it like this:

`xml.(localName()==yourlanguage).text()`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var xml:XML = <language lang = "ru">
        <ru>language/ru.xml</ru>
        <ua>language/uk.xml</ua>
        <en>language/en.xml</en>
        </language>;

    var string:String = String(xml[xml.@lang]);
    trace(string);
```

Prints "language/ru.xml"

Comment: Thank you. How i can get the name of the element or attribute?

Comment: @john You mean attribute value ("ru")? That's `xml.@lang`.